# Obter o objeto da linha selecionada com ng-grid Angular-UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou utilizando `ng-grid` do **Angular-UI** e preciso obter o objeto selecionado quando clicado na linha do grid.

Tenho a `function`:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(item)
{
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

Tentei sobre escrever a propriedade `rowTemplate` do objeto `gridOptions` para adicionar o a diretiva de click, desta forma:

```
rowTemplate:'<div ng-style="{ "cursor": row.cursor }" ng-repeat.....;
```

O código acima é o valor default, então adicionei na primeira `div` o `ng-click` para invocar a function:

```
rowTemplate:'<div ng-click="selectItem(o que passar aqui?)"ng-style.....;
```

Como eu acesso o objeto presente na linha clicada para passar em `selectItem`?

Answer (score 1):

Conferi a [documentação do ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/). Conforme o exemplo "Master/Details", você pode fazer assim:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mySelections = [];
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData',
      selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
      multiSelect: false
    };
});
```

O importante aqui é a opção `selectedItems` em `gridOptions`. Você inicializa um *array* vazio e usa na opção, que o array será atualizado com os itens selecionados.

Na documentação da API, a opção `selectedItems` está explicada assim:

> todos os itens selecionados no grid. No modo de seleção única (single select mode)
>   sempre haverá apenas um item no *array*.

---

#### Para ficar mais claro (passo-a-passo):

No teu `rowTemplate`, faça assim:

```
rowTemplate:'<div ng-click="selectItem(mySelections[0])" ng-style.....;
```

No teu `controller`, inclua:

```
$scope.mySelections = [];
```

E você vai precisar especificar a opção `selectedItems` em `gridOptions`:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { selectedItems: $scope.mySelections };
```

Ou seja, juntando tudo:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(item)
{
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
}

$scope.mySelections = [];

$scope.gridOptions =
{
    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
    rowTemplate:'<div ng-click="selectItem(mySelections[0])" ng-style...'
};
```

---

Na verdade, pode ficar mais simples. Em qualquer lugar do *controller* você tem acesso ao item selecionado com:

```
$scope.mySelections[0];
```

Ou no HTML (supondo que exista uma propriedade "name"):

```
<p>{{ mySelections[0].name }}</p>
```

Comment: Bom, na verdade não é isso. Eu preciso adicionar um evento de click na linha selecionada passando o objeto dela, por isso sobreescrevi o `rowTemplate`. Mas vou tentar fazer isso e te reporto, obrg.

Comment: Se você fizer como no exemplo, basta fazer `ng-click="selectItem(mySelections[0])"` no teu `rowTemplate`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com instruções passo-a-passo.